# Map pairs which are duplicate from 2 tables and find duplicate records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a 2 tables and one view which I want to find which pairs are duplicate:

```
    create table main_pairs(
       pair            text,
       id              integer
    )
    
-- view for second_pairs

create view second_pairs_view
        (pair, id) as
         SELECT (SELECT ap_1.pair
         FROM main_pairs ap_1
         WHERE ap_1.id = tp.pair) AS pair,
         tp.id
         FROM second_pairs tp
         LEFT JOIN main_pairs ap ON ap.id = tp.pair;


    create table second_pairs(
       pair         integer
    )


    INSERT INTO main_pairs (pair, id)
    
    VALUES ('London/Berlin', 1),
           ('London/Rome', 2),
           ('Paris/Berlin', 3),
           ('Paris/Budapest', 4),
           ('Oslo/Berlin', 5),
           ('Oslo/Berlin', 6),
           ('Huston/Berlin', 7);

    INSERT INTO second_pairs (pair)
    
    VALUES (6),
           (7),
           (8),
           (9),
```

As you can see I have a duplicate records 6 and 7. Using the view `second_pairs_view` how I can list the pairs which have duplicate records?

How I can check this with SQL query?

Comment: Your view does not use second_pairs. What is `tp`?

Comment: I consider 5 and 6 to be duplicated.

Comment: Sorry I updated the view, I found a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INNER JOIN` , it will return the matching records  :

```
  SELECT sp.pair
  from main_pairs mp 
  inner join second_pairs sp on mp.id=sp.pair;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ac47c8073c5241f74ab9e1225d7edc1a)

Comment: Is it possible to make the query without `create view....` In my case I can't create a view?

Comment: I updated the view code.

Comment: one thing is not clear. Maybe you need to select not `second_pairs sp` but `second_pairs_view`?

Comment: @user1285928 why you need the view ? You can do the join with the view , too. The view in the question produce an error

Comment: to get more accurate result.